# How to dynamically add cardview to grid layout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I am trying to add cardview to GridLayout dynamically. But it is not adding the cardview.

The Hierarchy is ScrollView --> HorizontalScrollView --> LinearLayout --> GridLayout and I want to add to this grid layout. my code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridLayout gridLayout;
TextView tc;
CardView newc;
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);

   newc = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
   newc.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   newc.setRadius(8);
   newc.setCardElevation(10);
   tc = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   tc.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   tc.setText("This is dynamic");
   newc.addView(tc);
   GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(0);
   GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(0);
   GridLayout.LayoutParams gridP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
   gridLayout.addView(newc, gridP);

}
}
```

So how to add the views dynamically to GridLayout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your code ... use this

```
newc = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
newc.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newc.setRadius(8);
 newc.setCardElevation(10);
tc = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tc.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tc.setText("This is dynamic");
newc.addView(tc);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
gridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
gridLayout.addView(newc);
```

If you want to add view to spcific row and specific column use this

```
 GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(0); // Mention row index here
   GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(0);// Mention column index here
   GridLayout.LayoutParams gridP = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
```

In your case, you are always using 0,0 for row and column so what basically happening is views are being added to grid layout but they are overlapping and hence you are unable to see those